# FFMPEG command to combine a WAV file and a video file?

Tags: windows, qt, opencv, ffmpeg, osx-snow-leopard

I use Qt & OpenCV to record video and QAudioInput to record audio into wav format. I want to combine them into one video file. How can I accomplish this? I have researched so much but I can't seem to find a command to accomplish this.

I use both Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this operation seems to be accomplished through the cmd-line [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1329333/176769). This approach may turn into an easy hack since you can call this command using `system()`.

But if you still want to do it programatically, I suggest you take a look at [Dranger's FFmpeg tutorials](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/). It provides 8 interesting tutorials that shows how to do simple stuff, from taking snapshots of a video to more complex stuffs like writing a simple video player with audio/video sync.

These tutorials teach how to work independently with audio and video streams, which is what you need to do: read the audio stream from the WAV file and then insert it as the audio stream of a video file.

Maybe not directly related to what you are aim for, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187745/audio-output-with-video-processing-with-opencv/8191506#8191506) demonstrates how to use FFmpeg to retrieve the audio stream of one file and play it with SDL, while simultaneously using OpenCV to retrieve video frames and display them in a SDL window.

Comment: yeah, i understanded, i combined successfull, i use Commanline: ffmpeg.exe -i 1.wav -i 1.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.avi but it have 1 issue is: after combined, when i play video then audio & video not sync, example: sounds occurring before the video show, how to sync audio & video record ???