# Decode audio and video and process both streams -- ffmpeg, sdl, opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, sdl

My goal is to proceed on audio and video of mpeg-2 file independently, and to keep synchronicity on both flows. Duration of video is about 1 or 2 minutes maximum.

1. First, following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187745/audio-output-with-video-processing-with-opencv) "opencv for reading videos (and do the process),ffmpeg for audio , and SDL used to play both" sounds perfect. I have done some modification on the code considering recent ffmpeg naming changes. Compilation with cmake on 64-bits machine is fine. I get an error "Unsupported codec [3]" when opening codec.
   The code is following.
2. Second, I looking for code dealing with synchronicity on both flows.

---

```
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv/cv.h"

#ifndef INT64_C
#define INT64_C(c) (c ## LL)
#define UINT64_C(c) (c ## ULL)
#endif

extern "C"{
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_thread.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
}

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace cv;

#define SDL_AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE 1024

typedef struct PacketQueue
{
   AVPacketList *first_pkt, *last_pkt;
   int nb_packets;
   int size;
   SDL_mutex *mutex;
   SDL_cond *cond;
} PacketQueue;
PacketQueue audioq;

int audioStream = -1;
int videoStream = -1;
int quit = 0;

SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;

AVFormatContext* pFormatCtx = NULL;
AVCodecContext* aCodecCtx = NULL;
AVCodecContext* pCodecCtx = NULL;

void show_frame(IplImage* img){
   if (!screen){
      screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(img->width, img->height, 0, 0);
      if (!screen){
         fprintf(stderr, "SDL: could not set video mode - exiting\n");
         exit(1);
      }
   }
   // Assuming IplImage packed as BGR 24bits
   SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom((void*)img->imageData,
                                                   img->width,
                                                   img->height,
                                                   img->depth * img->nChannels,
                                                   img->widthStep,
                                                   0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0
                                                  );

   SDL_BlitSurface(surface, 0, screen, 0);
   SDL_Flip(screen);
}

void packet_queue_init(PacketQueue *q){
   memset(q, 0, sizeof(PacketQueue));
   q->mutex = SDL_CreateMutex();
   q->cond = SDL_CreateCond();
}

int packet_queue_put(PacketQueue *q, AVPacket *pkt){
   AVPacketList *pkt1;
   if (av_dup_packet(pkt) < 0){
      return -1;
   }

   pkt1 = (AVPacketList*) av_malloc(sizeof(AVPacketList));
   //pkt1 = (AVPacketList*) malloc(sizeof(AVPacketList));
   if (!pkt1) return -1;
   pkt1->pkt = *pkt;
   pkt1->next = NULL;

   SDL_LockMutex(q->mutex);

   if (!q->last_pkt)
      q->first_pkt = pkt1;
   else
      q->last_pkt->next = pkt1;

   q->last_pkt = pkt1;
   q->nb_packets++;
   q->size += pkt1->pkt.size;
   SDL_CondSignal(q->cond);

   SDL_UnlockMutex(q->mutex);
   return 0;
}

static int packet_queue_get(PacketQueue *q, AVPacket *pkt, int block){
   AVPacketList *pkt1;
   int ret;

   SDL_LockMutex(q->mutex);
   for (;;){
      if( quit){
         ret = -1;
         break;
      }

      pkt1 = q->first_pkt;
      if (pkt1){
         q->first_pkt = pkt1->next;
         if (!q->first_pkt)
            q->last_pkt = NULL;

         q->nb_packets--;
         q->size -= pkt1->pkt.size;
         *pkt = pkt1->pkt;
         av_free(pkt1);
         //free(pkt1);
         ret = 1;
         break;
      }

      else if (!block){
         ret = 0;
         break;
      }
      else{
         SDL_CondWait(q->cond, q->mutex);
      }
   }

   SDL_UnlockMutex(q->mutex);
   return ret;
}

int audio_decode_frame(AVCodecContext *aCodecCtx, uint8_t *audio_buf, int buf_size){
   static AVPacket pkt;
   static uint8_t *audio_pkt_data = NULL;
   static int audio_pkt_size = 0;

   int len1, data_size;

   for (;;){
      while (audio_pkt_size > 0){
         data_size = buf_size;
         len1 = avcodec_decode_audio3(aCodecCtx, (int16_t*)audio_buf, &data_size, &pkt);
         if (len1 < 0){
            // if error, skip frame
            audio_pkt_size = 0;
            break;
         }
         audio_pkt_data += len1;
         audio_pkt_size -= len1;
         if (data_size <= 0){
            // No data yet, get more frames
            continue;
         }
         // We have data, return it and come back for more later
         return data_size;
     }

     if (pkt.data)
        av_free_packet(&pkt);
     if (quit) return -1;
     if (packet_queue_get(&audioq, &pkt, 1) < 0) return -1;
     audio_pkt_data = pkt.data;
     audio_pkt_size = pkt.size;
  }
}

void audio_callback(void *userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len){
  AVCodecContext *aCodecCtx = (AVCodecContext *)userdata;
  int len1, audio_size;

  static uint8_t audio_buf[(AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 3) / 2];
  static unsigned int audio_buf_size = 0;
  static unsigned int audio_buf_index = 0;

  while (len > 0){
     if (audio_buf_index >= audio_buf_size){
        // We have already sent all our data; get more
        audio_size = audio_decode_frame(aCodecCtx, audio_buf, sizeof(audio_buf));
        if(audio_size < 0){
           // If error, output silence
           audio_buf_size = 1024; // arbitrary?
           memset(audio_buf, 0, audio_buf_size);
        }
        else{
           audio_buf_size = audio_size;
        }
        audio_buf_index = 0;
    }

    len1 = audio_buf_size - audio_buf_index;
    if (len1 > len)
       len1 = len;
    memcpy(stream, (uint8_t *)audio_buf + audio_buf_index, len1);
    len -= len1;
    stream += len1;
    audio_buf_index += len1;
  }
}

     void setup_ffmpeg(char* filename)
     {
        if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, filename, NULL, NULL) != 0){
           fprintf(stderr, "FFmpeg failed to open file %s!\n", filename);
           exit(-1);
        }

        if (av_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx) < 0){
           fprintf(stderr, "FFmpeg failed to retrieve stream info!\n");
           exit(-1);
        }

        // Dump information about file onto standard error
        av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, 0, filename, 0);

        // Find the first video stream
        int i = 0;
        for (i; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++){
           if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO && videoStream < 0){
              videoStream = i;
           }

           if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO && audioStream < 0){
              audioStream = i;
           }
        }

        if (videoStream == -1){
           fprintf(stderr, "No video stream found in %s!\n", filename);
           exit(-1);
        }

        if (audioStream == -1){
           fprintf(stderr, "No audio stream found in %s!\n", filename);
           exit(-1);
        }

        // Get a pointer to the codec context for the audio stream
        aCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec;

        // Set audio settings from codec info
        SDL_AudioSpec wanted_spec;
        wanted_spec.freq = aCodecCtx->sample_rate;
        wanted_spec.format = AUDIO_S16SYS;
        wanted_spec.channels = aCodecCtx->channels;
        wanted_spec.silence = 0;
        wanted_spec.samples = SDL_AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE;
        wanted_spec.callback = audio_callback;
        wanted_spec.userdata = aCodecCtx;

        SDL_AudioSpec spec;
        if (SDL_OpenAudio(&wanted_spec, &spec) < 0){
           fprintf(stderr, "SDL_OpenAudio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
           exit(-1);
        }

        AVCodec* aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(aCodecCtx->codec_id);
        if (!aCodec){
           fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec [1]!\n");
           exit(-1);
        }
        avcodec_open(aCodecCtx, aCodec);

        // audio_st = pFormatCtx->streams[index]
        packet_queue_init(&audioq);
        SDL_PauseAudio(0);

        // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
        pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

        // Find the decoder for the video stream
        AVCodec* pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
        if (pCodec == NULL){
           fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec [2]!\n");
           exit(-1); // Codec not found
        }

        // Open codec
        if (avcodec_open(pCodecCtx, pCodec) < 0){
           fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec [3]!\n");
           exit(-1); // Could not open codec
        }
     }


     int main(int argc, char* argv[])
     {
        if (argc < 2){
            std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <video>" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        av_register_all();

        // Init SDL
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER))
        {
           fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
           return -1;
        }

        // Init ffmpeg and setup some SDL stuff related to Audio
        setup_ffmpeg(argv[1]);

        VideoCapture cap(argv[1]);
        if (!cap.isOpened()){
           std::cout << "Failed to load file!" << std::endl;
           return -1;
        }

        AVPacket packet;
        while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
        {
           if (packet.stream_index == videoStream)
           {
              // Actually this is were SYNC between audio/video would happen.
              // Right now I assume that every VIDEO packet contains an entire video frame, and that's not true. A video frame can be made by multiple packets!
              // But for the time being, assume 1 video frame == 1 video packet,
              // so instead of reading the frame through ffmpeg, I read it through OpenCV.

              Mat frame;
              cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

              // do some processing on the frame, either as a Mat or as IplImage.
              // For educational purposes, applying a lame grayscale conversion
              IplImage ipl_frame = frame;
              for (int i = 0; i < ipl_frame.width * ipl_frame.height * ipl_frame.nChannels; i += ipl_frame.nChannels)
              {
                 ipl_frame.imageData[i] = (ipl_frame.imageData[i] + ipl_frame.imageData[i+1] + ipl_frame.imageData[i+2])/3;   //B
                 ipl_frame.imageData[i+1] = (ipl_frame.imageData[i] + ipl_frame.imageData[i+1] + ipl_frame.imageData[i+2])/3; //G
                 ipl_frame.imageData[i+2] = (ipl_frame.imageData[i] + ipl_frame.imageData[i+1] + ipl_frame.imageData[i+2])/3; //R
              }

              // Display it on SDL window
              show_frame(&ipl_frame);

              av_free_packet(&packet);
           }
           else if (packet.stream_index == audioStream)
           {
              packet_queue_put(&audioq, &packet);
           }
           else
           {
              av_free_packet(&packet);
           }

           SDL_Event event;
           SDL_PollEvent(&event);
           switch (event.type)
           {
           case SDL_QUIT:
              SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
              SDL_Quit();
              break;

           default:
              break;
           }
        }

        // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor

        // Close the codec
        avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

        // Close the video file
        av_close_input_file(pFormatCtx);

        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: +1 Interesting question, Eric. Well written! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the "Unsupported codec" error. Remplace `AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO` with `AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO` in the following line :

```
if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO && audioStream < 0){
          audioStream = i;
}
```

Grayscale conversion is not true due to uchar opencv pixel format.
I still have the synchro not working ... any help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See  here for syncing:

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial06.html

and here:

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial07.html