# Process audio and video independently

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, portaudio, htk

due to the unpopularity of my last posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429342/decode-audio-and-video-and-process-both-streams-ffmpeg-sdl-opencv) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444208/process-audio-packets-decoded-with-ffmpeg)  , I'll try something else.
I have corresponding audio (.wav) and video files (.mpg). Let's consider that those two streams where recorded synchronously. I want to process both stream, with opencv for the images, and with "I don't know which audio lib" (you tell me ?) for audio, and I want to process those streams online and keep the synchronicity.
Note that the length of the video is less that 2 minutes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'process'? What are you trying to do with your audio and video streams?

Comment: What exactly is your aim? Are you saying that the audio for the video is in the wav file and not within the mpeg file and that you want to play the video with audio from a web page? Or are you trying to merge the audio into the video?

Comment: I am working on lipreading system. My database is in mpg-2. I want to extract relevant features from video and audio in real-time. The most important thing is that features extracted correspond in time. ex: MFCC extracted from audio in a small window correspond to HoG extracted from frames n°... etc ..

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "play" then WAV files require little work to output to a PCM signal, if you are running Linux (and maybe for other OS's too with there respective audio IO libs) this can then be streamed to alsa.